# Determinante de una matriz 3x3

Tags: c, funciones, bucles, fórmulas-de-matriz

Hola buenas noches tengo una duda sobre como hacer la operación para obtener el resultado de una determinante 3x3, he estado buscando ideas sobre como plantearlo en mi código pero no logro entenderlo :/, hasta ahorita solo llevo impresa la matriz, solo quiero que me expliquen por favor no hay necesidad de que me hagan el código.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

    int main()
    {   
    int matriz[3][3];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<=2;i++)  //Llenado de matriz
    {
        for (j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            printf ("Ingrese el valor de la matriz");
            scanf ("%d",&matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<=2;i++)  //Imprime la matriz 3x3
    {
        for (j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            printf (" %d",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }






}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para obtener el determinante de una matriz de orden 3X3 podes aplicar 2 metodos:

1. Sarrus: Esta orientado a matrices unicamente de este orden. La estrategia consiste en agregar al final de la matriz las primeras 2 filas de la misma e ir multiplicando cada elemento de cada diagonal (por izquierda y por derecha) creando un subconjunto de cada lado. La resta del subconjunto izquierdo y el derecho te da el determinante. Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que acabo de explicar para que sea mas util.

   Supongamos que tenes esta matriz:

   ```
     1  2  0
     3 -1  4
     5  2 -2
   ```

   1) Copiar las 2 primeras filas al final de la matriz

   ```
     1     2      0
     3    -1      4
     5     2     -2
     1     2      0
     3    -1      4
   ```

   2) La parte de crear los subconjuntos mencionada seria de la siguiente forma 
       https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxNpf.png (disculpa por la calidad)

   Tanto del lado izquierdo como del derecho se obtienen 3 sub conjuntos. 
      (1, -1, -2), (3, 2, 0) y (5, 2, 4) por parte de la izquierda

   (0, -1, 5), (4, 2, 1) y (-2, 2, 3) por parte de la derecha

   3) Como tercer paso tenes que multiplicar los elementos dentro de cada subconjunto y sumar los subconjuntos que sean de un mismo lado.

   Lado izquierdo: de este lado se obtiene de cada multiplicación los valores:
       2, proveniente del primer subconjunto izquierdo, 0, del segundo y 40 del tercero. Sumando estos valores se obtiene el numero 42. Es decir que el subconjunto izquierdo tiene como valor 42.

   Luego hacemos lo mismo con el derecho: se obtiene 0 del primer subconjunto, 8 del segundo y -12 del tercero. Sumando estos valores (8 + (-12)) = -4. Es decir que el subconjunto derecho tiene como valor -4.

   4) Como ultimo paso se deben restar los valores del subconjunto izquierdo con el derecho. 
         Subconjunto izquierdo - Subconjunto derecho= determinante

   ```
             42            -            (-4)     =     46
   ```

En conclusión, el determinante de la matriz es 46.

2. Como segunda opcion podes aplicar el metodo de LaPlace que esta orientado a matrices de orden NxN o simplemente de orden N. Tal que N>=3 ya que en matrices inferiores (como las de orden 2) el determinante se calcula haciendo el producto de la diagonal principal menos el de la secundaria, que mas adelante se utilizará. 
   Este teorima dice que la suma de los productos de cada elemento de una región (fila o columna) por el determinante de su matriz adjunta (seria una matriz de orden N-1) da como resultado el determinante de la misma.

   Utilizando la matriz del ejemplo anterior:

   ```
     1  2  0
     3 -1  4
     5  2 -2
   ```

   1) Seleccionas una fila o columna de la matriz cualquiera (para mayor facilidad se elije aquella que posee mas elementos en 0). Se elegirá la fila 1 `(1, 2, 0)`.

   2) Para calcular el determinante de la matriz de orden 2 (la adjunta de la original) lo que se hace es "tapar" la fila seleccionada y la columna que posee al elemento actual que la esta multiplicando. Es decir que si tengo el numero 1 de la fila que seleccione, tapo la columna 1, si tengo el 2, tapo la columna 2 y si tengo el 0 tapo la columna 3.

   Esto quedaria de la siguiente forma:

   1 * C11 + 2 * c12 + 0 * c13

Donde los subindices de c corresponde a la fila y columna a tapar de la matriz y Cxy es el determinante de la porción sobrante.

C11= det(

```
 -1  4 
  2 -2
```

) = (-1 * -2) - (2 * 4) = -6 * cofactor del elemento = 1 -> -6

C12= det(

```
  3  4      
  5 -2
```

)= (3 * -2) - (5 * 4) = -26 * cofactor del elemento = -1 -> 26

C13= det(

```
  3 -1
  5  2
```

)= (3 * 2) - (5 * -1) = 11 * cofactor del elemento = 1 -> 11

PD: el cofactor del elemento se haya sumando los subindices x e y y si el resultado es un numero par, el valor es 1, de lo contrario es -1.

```
Entonces para concluir, el determinante es:
```

1 * (-6) + 2 * (26) + 0 * 11  = -6 + 52 = 46

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue muy útil también tu comentario logre entender como funciona el programa.

Answer (score 3):

Tendrias que hacer Sarrows y para eso recorrer la matriz en diagonal. 
Te dejo un link donde hay codigo de los for para hacer esto.

recorrido IZQ - DER

```
for(i =0; i<f; i++){
 for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c-i ; j++) {
    }
}
```

recorrido DER - IZQ

```
    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
       for (int j = c-i; j<c; j++) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: +1 felicidades buena y útil respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Agrega al inicio la declaracion de las siguientes variables:

```
int x, y; 
int determinante = 0;
```

De acuerdo a la distribucion de las cifras en las matriz, puedes agregar el siguiente ciclo for para la obtencion del determinante:

```
for (j=0; j<=2; j++){

if (j==0) {
x=1;
y=2;    
}

if (j==1) {
x=0;
y=2;    
}

if (j==2) {
x=0;
y=1;    
}

 determinante += matriz[0][j]*(matriz[1][x]*matriz[2][y]-matriz[1][y]*matriz[2][x]);
}

printf("El determinante es: %d", determinante);
```